# How do I create a temporary table to sort the same column by two criteria using Django's ORM?

Tags: mysql, django

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP (SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN_A);
SELECT * FROM TEMP ORDER BY COLUMN_B;
```

I have a table stores every city's last 24 hours pm point, I want to select the latest pm point of every city.So I use "Select * from city_pm order by date desc limit the_count_of_city", then I want to have a rank of the latest pm point of every city, so I use the select before to create a temporary table, and order the table by pm point...this is what I'm attempting to accomplish, I can't figure out a better way so I decide to create a temporary table.

Comment: I doubt this is at all possible in mysql itself

Comment: @jimy: Temporary tables exist: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html Did you mean that?

Comment: @Teddy: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What is the reason behind the temporary table? Why not ordering by both columns at the same time?

Comment: I'm also curious to the purpose of a temporary table. If the goal is to sort results, then your RAM which stores the results of a table search using Django's ORM should be able to hold the data in memory. From there, it's technically satisfying the basic needs of a temporary short term data storage for the process at hand. A temporary table for other purposes like a cache is different. Can you share more of the entire scope of what you're attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks, @TimSelatyJr. This is my situation: I have a table stores every city's last 24 hours pm point, I want to select the latest pm point of every city.So I use "Select * from city_pm order by date desc limit the_count_of_city", then I want to have a rank of the latest pm point of every city, so I use the select before to create a temporary table, and order the table by pm point...this is what I'm attempting to accomplish, I can't figure out a better way so I decide to create a temporary table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe left join's may assist in this situation. Your goal is to order cities by the last PM point.

Assuming the primary key of your `city` table is city_id, and a separate table called `city_pm` holds the PM points, and that you have two models City and City_Pm...

In your view:

```
cities = City.objects.all()
```

In your models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    # fields ...

    def get_latest_pm(self):
        try:
            return City_Pm.objects.filter(city_id=self.pk).order_by("-date")[:1].get()
        except:
            return None
```

In your template:

```
{% for city in cities %}
    {{ city.get_latest_pm }}
{% endfor %}
```