# How to create a temporary table and not lose the ORM in django?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I'm curious how to create a temporary table in django? (the database is mysql, a client requirement)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE somewhat_like_a_cache AS
(SELECT * FROM expensive_query_with_multiple_joins);
SELECT * FROM somewhat_like_a_cache LIMIT 1000 OFFSET X;
```

The reasoning behind this:
The resultset is fairly large and I have to iterate it. The expensive query takes around 30 seconds. Without a temporary table I stress the database server for several hours. With the temporary table the expensive query is executed only once and iterating the temporary table in slices is cheap afterwards.

This is no duplicate of 
[How do I create a temporary table to sort the same column by two criteria using Django's ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162611/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-django-with-orm). The author just wanted to sort by two columns.

Comment: Can a view not substitute for this? Plus, it won't disappear once you close the connection.

Comment: To my knowledge it'd be just as slow as the initial query.

Comment: You may want to look at queryset caching something like johnny cache http://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/

Answer (score 6):

I have came to this problem and I built a function to sync models to the database (adapted from the management script `syncdb`.

you can write your temporary models any where in your code or even generate the models in the run-time then call `sync_models`. and enjoy the `ORM`

its database independent by the way and can be used with any `django` supported database backend

```
from django.db import connection
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.management.color import no_style
from importlib import import_module


def sync_models(model_list):
    '''
    Create the database tables for given models.
    '''
    tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
    seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
    created_models = set()
    pending_references = {}
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for model in model_list:
        # Create the model's database table, if it doesn't already exist.
        sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, no_style(), seen_models)
        seen_models.add(model)
        created_models.add(model)
        for refto, refs in references.items():
            pending_references.setdefault(refto, []).extend(refs)
            if refto in seen_models:
                sql.extend(connection.creation.sql_for_pending_references(refto, no_style(), pending_references))
        sql.extend(connection.creation.sql_for_pending_references(model, no_style(), pending_references))
        for statement in sql:
            cursor.execute(statement)
        tables.append(connection.introspection.table_name_converter(model._meta.db_table))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested following in Postgresql (also using it rarely), but I do not think you will have any problem.

Django also offers you an api for executing custom SQL Queries (`INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE, DROP` etc) using `connection`. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) about the usage

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor() #  create the cursor

cursor.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_table (code char(5)  PRIMARY KEY,
                                                   title varchar(40) NOT NULL);")
cursor.execute("INSERT into test_table (code, title) values ('ABVCD', 'This is my Title');")
cursor.execute("select * from test_table;") #  now select all data in our table
print cursor.fetchall() # and fetch them all
cursor.close()  # if you wish to close it
```

This is an example code I tested withj Postgresql 9.1, but you will not have any problem if you execute queries suitable to your DBMS version.

Using `TEMPORARY` tables or creating normal tables and executing drop statement after you finished your job is up to you. But read the docs before you begin.

Comment: I know of this functionality, it leaves the ORM behind though.

Comment: How do you planning to use ORM and `Temporary` tables at the same time? There is another option (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) where you can use custom queries over django ORM, but you **must** have create models and **syncdb** them to your DBMS before you can use them. So writing a script that will create an application, write down a `models.py` and add it to your applications in `settings.py` and then ,syncdb` it and remove it after use? It do not look like a good approach to me. May be what you need is to create a model and insert/delete there

Comment: It should be possible to generate models at runtime. The types of the fields could be derived from the query that creates the temporary table.

Comment: It would be hard since when you define a class that extends `django.db.models.Model`, it will look for the application label which your model lives in to set some related values (database table names for example). In this case, you either create directories and files and edit them, or try to find a solution to overcome application based errors. `raw` let you execute model based queries but AFAIK it is limited to `SELECT` queries only.

Comment: @FallenAngel - Is it possible to use it to copy an existing model like a clone, maybe? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but the ORM itself is much like a temporary store. Say you have a users table and wish to create a temporary users table of the first 10 users, you could create a list to hold the values and use a list methods to sort, filter, etc.
If the computation is expensive you can use packages like numpy: https://numpy.org/

Comment: Sorry, that's not at all what I've been looking for. 

If the operation is expensive in code, than it's preferable to do the operation in the database  in most cases: For the operation to become expensive the resultset needs to be large whch is expensive itself.